# Attempting to make a website with only a container with pointing at a specific site

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a website with a container for Google that bypasses extensions like Hapara or Securly. My code for what is on the website mainly is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google</title>
        <blockquote class="embedly-card"><h4><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></h4><p>Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for.</p></blockquote>
<script async src="//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/platform.js" charset="UTF-8"></script></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not exactly sure what to do. I'm using Google Apps Script so I can share the entire thing for you to check out the entire code.

Comment: Welcome. Your question is a bit vague. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Also, your markup needs help. It's missing a closing `head` tag, an opening `body` tag, and has an extra closing `script` tag.